# Ethereum Wallet can't sync - wifi issue

Tags: connections

I'm newbie having a few Eth issues, to begin with:
Trying to run Ethereum Wallet 0.8.0 on my x64 linux my internet connection becomes intermittent. If a ping is left running (say 8.8.8.8), when the EW starts I start getting "Destination Port Unreachable" with maybe 1 in 4 or 5 pings still replying. Nothing else breaks my wifi connection like this.

In the terminal I started EW from messages say "mini-api.cryptocompare.com’s server DNS address could not be found". When I CTRL-C to stop EW the pings go back to normal.

Could please do with some steps to troubleshoot or clue where to look. Testing with a wired connection is difficult.

Comment: check your firewall and upgrad you EW to 0.8.3